# rename Qty at 'add to cart' in Spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

[image]

I'd like to rename "Qty" into "Quantity"

Follow things I already tried:

---

In 'spartacus-configuration.module.ts'

```
i18n: {
  resources: {
    en: {
      product: {
        addToCart: {
          quantity: 'Quantity'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

in src/assets/i18n-assets/en/produkt

```
{
   ...
   "addToCart": {
       ...
       "quantity": "Quantity",
       ...
    },
    ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to overwrite translation values is to provide a new resource in `app.module.ts` config.

Firstly, new object with specific translations should be defined:

```
export const translationOverwrites = {
  en: {
    product: {
      addToCart: {
        quantity: 'Quantity',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

and then it should be provided after default Spartacus translations:

```
...  
providers: [
  provideConfig({
    i18n: { resources: translations },
  }),
  provideConfig({
    i18n: { resources: translationOverwrites },
  }),
],
```

Example code can look like this:

```
import { translations } from '@spartacus/assets';
import { provideConfig } from '@spartacus/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { I18nModule } from '@spartacus/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SpartacusModule } from './spartacus/spartacus.module';

export const translationOverwrites = {
  en: {
    product: {
      addToCart: {
        quantity: 'Quantity',
      },
    },
  },
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
    SpartacusModule,
    I18nModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    provideConfig({
      i18n: { resources: translations },
    }),
    provideConfig({
      i18n: { resources: translationOverwrites },
    }),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

For more information please look into Spartacus documentation: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/i18n/#overwriting-individual-translations