# Custom validations in spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am new to spartacus and am using the registration form with custom validations for name. I have added the validation in the .ts file as

```
firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z]+$')]],
```

On UI I get `[common:formErrors.pattern]`
How to I use custom validations?

Answer (score 0):

I think you get such value because you need to provide a translation for `pattern` key.

Please see my other answer about how to add/override translation values: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68923798/13845333

Also there is whole section regarding to Internationalization in Spartacus docs: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/i18n/